# Theory of Sets - apply even odd rule

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can anyone help me how to create tikz picture for these images.
Thank you a a lot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\def\A{(0.5, 1) .. controls ++(180:-1) and ++(280: 2) .. (2.5, 3) .. controls ++(280:-1) and ++(170: -.5) .. (.5, 3) .. controls ++(170: 1) and ++(180: 1) .. (0.5, 1);}
\def\B{(1.5, 2) .. controls ++(150:-2) and ++(280: 1) .. ( 4.5, 2.5) .. controls ++(280:-1) and ++(180:-1) .. ( 3, 4) .. controls ++(180: 1) and ++(175:-1) .. (1, 4.5) .. controls ++(175: 1) and ++(150: 1) .. (1.5,2);}
\def\R{(-1,0) rectangle (5,5);}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thick] \R; 
    \begin{scope} \clip \A; 
    \fill[gray] \B; 
    \end{scope} 
    \draw \A; \draw \B; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: My try]

Comment: Search here for `even odd rule`, you'll find many interesting stuff to begin with. But don't expect members of this site to draw all these for you. Come back with what you tried and with specific questions.

Comment: Thank you, #SebGlav! I was not expecting anyone to draw all of these. I was hoping, as you did, someone to give me some light on this issue!

Comment: I prepared a few examples on how to use `scope`, `clip` and `even odd rule`, but the post is closed for now. Maybe if you edit your question with a simple MWE showing what you tried, I'd be able to share them with you.

Comment: I tried this:
\def\A{(0.5, 1) 
.. controls ++(180:-1) and ++(280: 2) .. (2.5, 3)
.. controls ++(280:-1) and ++(170: -.5) .. (.5, 3)
.. controls ++(170: 1) and ++(180: 1) .. (0.5, 1);}
\def\B{(1.5, 2) 
.. controls ++(150:-2) and ++(280: 1) .. ( 4.5, 2.5)
.. controls ++(280:-1) and ++(180:-1) .. ( 3, 4)
.. controls ++(180: 1) and ++(175:-1) .. (1, 4.5)
.. controls ++(175: 1) and ++(150: 1) .. (1.5,2);}
\def\R{(-1,0) rectangle (5,5);}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick] \R;
\begin{scope}
\clip \A;
\fill[gray] \B;
\end{scope}
\draw \A;
\draw \B;
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: I've edited your post to add your code which is pretty much a good start on what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to draw the others.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here are four examples of what you can do (you may find a way to achieve everything else from that starting point). You already did it well.

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

[image: Example 3]

[image: Example 4]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \def\a{(1,3.5)(2,4.5)(3,3.5)(3.5,4)(4,3.5)(3.5,2.5)(4.5,1.5)(4.5,1)(3.5,1)(3.5,2)(1.5,2.5)}
    \def\b{(.5,.5)(1,2)(2.5,3)(2,1)}
    \def\A{plot[smooth cycle,tension=.75] coordinates {\a}}
    \def\B{plot[smooth cycle,tension=1] coordinates {\b}}
        
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[orange,even odd rule] \A \B;
        \draw[orange!50!black] \A \B;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip \A;
            \fill[orange] \B;
        \end{scope}
        \draw[orange!50!black] \A \B;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[even odd rule]
            \clip \A;
            \fill[orange,even odd rule] \A \B;
        \end{scope}
        \draw[orange!50!black] \A \B;
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[even odd rule]
            \clip \B;
            \fill[orange,even odd rule] \A \B;
        \end{scope}
        \draw[orange!50!black] \A \B;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, SebGlav!

Comment: @EmanuelFurtado If this answer suits you, feel free to upvote and accept it. If you need more details, please feel free to ask in the comments.